# React conditional render for logged in / logged out User only updates state with browser refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-state, react-state-management, conditional-rendering

I'm building a React app using hooks and functional components for the front end to a Rails backend API with Cookie / Session authentication. Everything is working well as far as getting users logged in, signed up, logged out etc. The problem I'm having now is that I'm trying to conditionally render the Navbar to show the appropriate CRUD action links - `Logout` button, `avatar`, `Profile` and `Update Profile` links when logged in, and of course, not show that but a `Sign Up` and `Login` button when not logged in.

It sort of works. I log or sign up with a user and I'm redirected to the `Dashboard` page but the `Nav` stays static. I click browser refresh, and voila, the state updates to what a logged in user should see. The same thing happens on logout. What could be going on?

Dependencies: axios, react-router-dom v6, a private route and custom hook to check auth for the private route.

```
// App.js 
import axios from 'axios';

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

import Nav from './components/Nav';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import About from './pages/About';
import SignUp from './pages/auth/SignUp';
import SignIn from './pages/auth/SignIn';
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';

function App() {
  const [loggedInStatus, setLoggedInStatus] = useState('NOT_LOGGED_IN');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3001/logged_in', { withCredentials: true })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('resp from server', response);
        if (response.data.logged_in && loggedInStatus === 'NOT_LOGGED_IN') {
          setLoggedInStatus('LOGGED_IN');
          setUserData(response.data.user);
        } else if (
          !response.data.logged_in &
          (loggedInStatus === 'LOGGED_IN')
        ) {
          setLoggedInStatus('NOT_LOGGED_IN');
          setUserData({});
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('check login error', error);
      });
  }, []);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setLoggedInStatus(false);
    setUserData({});
    navigate('/');
  };

  const handleLogoutClick = () => {
    axios
      .delete('http://localhost:3001/logout', { withCredentials: true })
      .then((response) => {
        handleLogout();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('logout error', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Nav
        handleLogoutClick={handleLogoutClick}
        loggedInStatus={loggedInStatus}
      />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/sign-up' element={<SignUp />} />

        <Route path='/sign-in' element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
        <Route path='/dashboard' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />

          <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/*' element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>

      <ToastContainer
        position='top-right'
        autoClose={5000}
        hideProgressBar={false}
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Navbar. I originally built this with inline conditionals to keep it DRY but thought maybe that was causing it to render late / not at all, so I rebuilt it with two full returns instead.

```
// Nav
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BiPlusMedical } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CgProfile } from 'react-icons/cg';
import axios from 'axios';

function Nav({ handleLogoutClick }) {
  const [loggedInStatus, setLoggedInStatus] = useState('NOT_LOGGED_IN');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3001/logged_in', { withCredentials: true })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('resp from server', response);
        if (response.data.logged_in && loggedInStatus === 'NOT_LOGGED_IN') {
          setLoggedInStatus('LOGGED_IN');
          setUserData(response.data.user);
        } else if (
          !response.data.logged_in &
          (loggedInStatus === 'LOGGED_IN')
        ) {
          setLoggedInStatus('NOT_LOGGED_IN');
          setUserData({});
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('check login error', error);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loggedInStatus === 'LOGGED_IN') {
    return (
      <div className='navbar shadow-lg bg-neutral text-neutral-content '>
        <div className='flex-none px-2 mx-2'>
          <span className='text-lg font-bold'>Neighbour</span>
          <span className='aid-icon bg-white p-1 rounded-full mx-1'>
            <BiPlusMedical style={{ color: 'red' }} />
          </span>
          <span className='text-lg font-bold'>Aid</span>
        </div>
        <div className='flex-1 px-2 mx-2'>
          <div className='items-stretch hidden lg:flex'>
            <Link to='/' className='btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn'>
              Home
            </Link>

            <Link to='/dashboard' className='btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn'>
              Portfolio
            </Link>

            <Link to='/about' className='btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn'>
              Learn More
            </Link>
            <a className='btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn'>Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='flex-none mx-2'>
          <Link to='/'>
            <button
              className='btn btn-md btn-ghost'
              onClick={handleLogoutClick}
            >
              Logout
            </button>
          </Link>
        </div>

        <div className='flex-none mx-2'>
          <div className='avatar'>
            <div className='rounded-full w-10 h-10 m-1'>
              <img src='https://i.pravatar.cc/500?img=32' />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div className='navbar shadow-lg bg-neutral text-neutral-content '>
        <div className='flex-none px-2 mx-2'>
          <span className='text-lg font-bold'>Neighbour</span>
          <span className='aid-icon bg-white p-1 rounded-full mx-1'>
            <BiPlusMedical style={{ color: 'red' }} />
          </span>
          <span className='text-lg font-bold'>Aid</span>
        </div>
        <div className='flex-1 px-2 mx-2'>
          <div className='items-stretch hidden lg:flex'>
            <Link to='/' className='btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn'>
              Home
            </Link>

            <Link to='/about' className='btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn'>
              Learn More
            </Link>
            <a className='btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn'>Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='flex-none mx-2'>
          <Link to='sign-in'>
            <button className='btn btn-md btn-ghost'>Login</button>
          </Link>
        </div>

        <div className='flex-none mx-2'>
          <Link to='/sign-up'>
            <button className='btn btn-md btn-ghost '>Get Started</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className='flex-none mx-2'>
          <div className='avatar'>
            <div className='rounded-full w-10 h-10 m-1 '>
              <CgProfile className='flex text-3xl' />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here's the Private Route and custom hook for checking auth

```
//useAuthState.js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

export const useAuthStatus = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [checkingStatus, setCheckingStatus] = useState(true);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted) {
      axios
        .get('http://localhost:3001/logged_in', { withCredentials: true })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.data.logged_in) {
            setLoggedIn(true);
            setUserData(response.data.user);
          }
          setCheckingStatus(false);
        });
    }

    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return { loggedIn, setLoggedIn, checkingStatus, userData, setUserData };
};
```

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuthStatus } from '../hooks/useAuthStatus';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

function PrivateRoute() {
  const { loggedIn, checkingStatus } = useAuthStatus();

  if (checkingStatus) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return loggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/sign-in' />;
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

I also tried doing the get request for logged in use in the Nav by using the getAuthState hook (which would be ideal to keep it clean) but it did the same thing so I figured maybe the was something in the asynchronous nature of what's happening that threw it off - so I put the get request at component level.

Any thoughts on what's going on would be very helpful.

Comment: You are doing the axios call again in the navbar, so it only would get the correct state after the useEffect has been executed. generally you should think of changing the pattern of your application auth managment and use context to achieve this. You would make 1 Call and update the context state and based on that all components with that state will be accordingly updated.

Comment: Aside from the pattern that was mentioned above, it appears that your useEffect in the Nav component is written to fire only once on render.  Does adding [userData] to the useEffect dependency array fix things for you?

Comment: I actually had all of this in Context in an earlier version but ran into a different problem - but you are right ... I think one "universal" spot for checking auth is the best way to go. Sadly, simply adding the `useData` to the `useEffect` dependency hasn't solved it yet. I also had the axios get request passed down as props but that didnt' solve it either.

Comment: Maybe Context is the best, most comprehensive answer? I dunno. This is a graded project so the simplest solution is acceptable (though of course I'd love to understand why I'm getting the behaviour I'm observing).

Comment: None of these options have solved the issue of the Navbar not re-rendering unless I manually refresh the browser. I initially added the second axios call in `useEffect` to the Nav bar to give it component level access to the loggedInState but even brining it in by props from `App.js`  so that it makes only 1 call to the serve doesn't yield better results.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a basic example of how you would use context and state to check user Auth:

```
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const Context = createContext();

export default function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const value = { loggedIn, setLoggedIn };

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={value}>
      <MyComponent />
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

function MyComponent() {
  const { loggedIn, setLoggedIn } = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setLoggedIn((prev) => !prev)}>
        {loggedIn ? "log out" : "log in"}
      </button>
      <div>{loggedIn ? " logged in " : "not logged in"}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

You would need to update your state at one place based on the axios call ( I didnt use it in this example, but the concept is the same.

Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-currying-s88lf?file=/src/App.js